# Let $S_1, S_2, \dots , S_m$ be distinct subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ such that $|S_i \cap S_j | = 1$ for all $i \ne j$. Prove that $m \le n$.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-proofs, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Let $S_1, S_2, \dots , S_m$ be distinct subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ such that $|S_i \cap S_j | = 1$ for all $i \ne j$. Prove that $m \le n$.

I got this problem from the double counting handout ( [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BqfBiLf1GTU_tJD20SeOZkI91OMc1Pu7/view)).

Progress: Well define $X_i$ as the set of sets which contain $i$ as an element. So note that $X_1+\dots +X_n=|S_1|+|S_2|+\dots+|S_m|$.

Also if $\{S_i\}=\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ then we have $(X_{a_1}-1)+(X_{a_2}-1)+\dots+(X_{a_k}-1)=m-1$ as every element $a_j$ is there in $X_{a_j}$ sets including $S_i$. So we get that $X_{a_1}+X_{a_2}+\dots+X_{a_k}-|S_i|=m-1$.

Well, let's write it as $X_{a_1}+X_{a_2}+\dots+X_{a_k}=m-1+ |S_i|$. And now sum, so we get RHS as $m(m-1)+|S_1|+\dots+|S_m|= m(m-1)+X_1+\dots +X_n$.
And then $a_i$ appears in $X_{a_i}$ sets. So we have LHS as $(X_1)^2+\dots (X_n)^2$.

So we have $(X_1)^2+\dots (X_n)^2=  m(m-1)+X_1+\dots +X_n\implies (X_1)(X_1-1)+\dots (X_n)(X_n-1)=  m(m-1)$

Any solutions?

Comment: this is a special case of Fisher Inequality and typically proven with linear algebra.  Ref e.g. miniature #4 here: https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any combinatorial proof of this, I doubt that there is a simple one which does not somehow interpret the following argument.

Assume that $|S_i|>1$. If not (say $|S_1|=1$), the family forms a sunflower, $(S_i\setminus S_1)$ partitions $[n]$, and the proposition follows trivially.

Assuming now that $|S_i|>1$, form the incidence matrix of the family and call it $M_{n\times m}$. Clearly for $u\in\{0,1\}^n$ interpreted as a subset $U\subseteq [n]$, $(uM)_i$ counts $|S_i\cap U|$. Then it follows that for $V=M^TM$, $$V_{ij} = |A_i\cap A_j|$$
It is easy to verify that the columns of $V$ are all linearly independent, and so the rank of $V$ is $m$. But since $\mathsf{rank}(V)\leq\mathsf{rank}(M)\leq n$, the proposition follows.